# WPF style cells and rows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want replace styles rows and cells in DataGrid.  But, i can apply my custom style only one: rows or cells. Example on code below:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{ Binding FinalCalculatingData}" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
          CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMerged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                    <Border  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Grid.Column="1">
                                                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                                        <Run Text="{Binding NameNull}"/>
                                                    </TextBlock.Inlines>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </Border>
                                            <DataGridRowHeader SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

<!-- etc -->
</DataGrid>
```

How i can apply my style to rows and cells at the same time?

**UPD1:**

[image]

**UPD2**

Here, I added the ControlTemplate code for the row using your edits. Selecting the line began to work, but without color.

code:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
   BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" x:Name="SelectedMergedRow">
<SelectiveScrollingGrid>
<SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
<SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
<DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" 
   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
<DataGridCellsPresenter.Template>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
   <DataGridCell Height="20">
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NameNull}"/>
      <DataGridCell.Style>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
               </DataTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </DataGridCell.Style>
   </DataGridCell>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and gif:

[image]

Comment: Set both the `RowStyle` and the `CellStyle` property?

Comment: @mm8 I update my post and add code. If I add this line style, then it no longer stands out. And my own mesh style doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand. What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens? How does it look and how do you expect it to look like?

Comment: @mm8 one moment.

Comment: @mm8 The line with my style no longer stands out. And I would like it to stand out like the rest of the cells. I established the post, added gif. Adding style to cells does not help.

Comment: Please clarify what "stand out" means?

Comment: @mm8 Highlight in color :) Like any of the standard cells.

Comment: That's because you have define a custom ControlTemplate without any triggers...why did you this?

Comment: @mm8 My target - create cell, which is composed is a few standart cells. How on gif.

Comment: If you want the highlighting, you need to include it in your template.

Comment: @mm8 Please, say - how this make?

Comment: There is more to it than removing the `DataGridCellsPresenter` from the style. Please refer to my answer. It should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the cells from a `DataGridRow` and expect it to behave as usual. You could try to define a custom Style for the `DataGridCellsPresenter` but you still need to make sure that row is selected when you click on the custom row. Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                <DataGridCellsPresenter.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
                        <DataGridCell Height="20">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" />
                            <DataGridCell.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridCell.Style>
                        </DataGridCell>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </DataGridCellsPresenter.Template>
            </DataGridCellsPresenter>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

```
private void DataGridCell_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)sender;
    DataGrid dataGrid = FindParent<DataGrid>(cell);
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = cell.DataContext;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null) return null;
    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thank! He screwed up, everything works, except for changing the color of the selected line ... How can I fix it?

Comment: @Range: Just replace `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}` with the brush (colour) you want.

Comment: Sorry me, i maked this, but cell keeped white color at change property IsSelected. I update post above, add block DataGridCell style and gif with demonstration.

Comment: @Range: You need to style the *row*. Did you really try my sample markup?

Answer (score 0):

hi to use a CellStyle use the `DataGrid.CellStyle` property on the datagrid.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <!-- my style -->
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: I update my post and add code. If I add this line style, then it no longer stands out. And my own mesh style doesn't work.